# perl <file.pl> gets executed with no output at all

Tags: bash, shell, perl, scripting, cmusphinx

I downloaded a perl script (http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/download/quick_lm.pl) for generating language models.

When I do `perl quick_lm.pl`, it simply terminates. No output at all.

- Yes, I have perl installed and `perl -v` works perfectly.
- I made a simple hello-world perl script and it executes just fine. [attached at the end]
- So, I included `print "hello";` in the first line of the `quick_lm.pl` and tried `perl quick_lm.pl`, still nothing happens.

I even tried giving the `quick_lm.pl` all permissions using `chmod 777 quick_lm.pl`. Now when I do `./quick_lm.pl` it gives an error :

```
-bash: ./quick_lm.pl: /usr/local/bin/perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I searched this error and almost all the solutions pointed to windows CLRF, but unlike them I do not have `^M` in `/usr/local/bin/perl`. Also, still `perl quick_lm.pl` should work, right?

---

[bash.log]

```
someone@something:~/dictionary$ perl quick_lm.pl
someone@something:~/dictionary$ perl quick_lm.pl -s words.txt 
someone@something:~/dictionary$ nano quick_lm.pl 
someone@something:~/dictionary$ perl quick_lm.pl -s words.txt 
someone@something:~/dictionary$ chmod 777 quick_lm.pl 
someone@something:~/dictionary$ ./quick_lm.pl 
-bash: ./quick_lm.pl: /usr/local/bin/perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
someone@something:~/dictionary$ cat new.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 
use strict;

print "Hello World\n";
someone@something:~/dictionary$ perl new.pl 
Hello World
someone@something:~/dictionary$
```

[After adding `print` in the beginning of `quick_lm.pl` and reducing it to a minimal, runable demonstration of the problem.]

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
=POD

...license...

=END

use Getopt::Std;

print "hello world";
$VERBOSE = 1;

sub handler { local($sig) = @_;
          print STDERR "quick_lm caught a SIG$sig -- dying\n";

          exit(0);
        }
foreach (qw(XCPU KILL TERM STOP)) { $SIG{$_} = \&handler; }
```

This is not full script, full script is in the link mentioned in the very first line. I am not sure if it's related to file as much as my perl configuration. As you might have guessed, I don't have much idea about perl.

I appreciate your time and help :)

Comment: Where is your `perl` installed?  What do you get when you type `command -v perl`?  Perhaps it's `/usr/bin/perl` instead of `/usr/local/bin/perl`?

Comment: @EricRenouf You're right about that part. It indeed was installed at `/usr/bin/perl`. I edited the file to `#!/usr/bin/perl -w` and no it doesn't give error but again, no output.

Comment: I can't reproduce your results now, if I copy and paste the script above I get a warning then "hello world" though without a new line so it might be "hiding" beside the prompt

Comment: @ikegami I am not removing license at all. I removed the license only in the question so that it is easier to read. I have linked the original file as well. I am happy to include the licenses back.

Comment: @ikegami If I work with the intact file, I get the problems mentioned in the question. If I remove the lines from `=POD` to `=END`, it works.

Comment: @ikegami Not sure why this got downvoted. I made sure I searched things, included all the information along with examples and tried cases, included minimal runnable demo, wrote observations, made detailed edits. What am I missing?

Comment: Who knows. I upvoted so you wouldn't be negative.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you so much! I really wish it becomes mandatory to quote the reason while downvoting, even if it be anon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *`-bash: ./quick_lm.pl: /usr/local/bin/perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`*

Replace `/usr/local/bin/perl` with the correct path to `perl`. This path can be obtained from

```
perl -le'print $^X'
```

---

> *it simply terminates. No output at all.*

The `=pod` directive indicates the start of inlined documentation ("[POD](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html)"). `=cut` marks the end of the block of POD.

The program incorrectly uses `=END` instead of `=cut` to mark the end of the block of POD, so Perl thinks the whole program is one big comment.. Replace `=END` with `=cut`.

Comment: The thing to note is, it is case sensitive. `=CUT` doesn't work, but `=cut` works!

Comment: @Saurabh Shrivastava, True, but that has nothing to do with the question. the program in the question used `=END` instead of `=cut`.

Comment: I am not criticising, just commenting in order to inform future seekers! :) Thanks to you, I got it to work without tampering with license.